# How to check all check boxes in form application programatically?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, checkbox

I want to check all checkboxes when click on the button. All object are in form application of visual studio 2010 c++. The point of problem is that every object (checkbox) has various name, CheckBox1, CheckBox2, ... I make UnicodeString with value "CheckBox", and int value that begin with 1, and put it together in third variable to find object, and that's work, but don't have a clue how to check all those boxes, please help.

Windows 7, 64, Visual studio 2010(c++) or c++ builder 2010

Comment: In Win32 API proper, checkboxes don't have names - they have numeric IDs. I think you're using C++ Builder's library (is it still called OWL?) and mistaking it for WinAPI. Retag please.

Comment: Which is it? C++ Builder or Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: They're not the same. I don't know everything I should about C++ Builder, but I understand it provides a custom wrapper library around the Win32 API. If you're using that library, the code you write targeting it is *not* going to transfer to Visual C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar for another component, this is how I did using C++ Builder.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this->ComponentCount; i++)
{
 TCheckBox *TempCheckBox = dynamic_cast<TCheckBox *>(this->Components[i]);
 if (TempCheckBox)
 {
   TempCheckBox->Checked = true;
 }
}
```

This will iterate through all the components on your form, if the component is a TCheckBox it will be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you add everything to a vector containing checkboxes, and then iterate through them all when necessary? This will allow you to reference each checkbox individually, but yet all at once.

```
     cliext::vector<System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^> items;
     items.push_back(checkbox1);
     .
     .
     .
     items.push_back(checkboxN);
```

It is important that you also include

```
#include <cliext/vector>
```

due to the fact that the normal vector in the standard library is currently unable to support this control.

Comment: yes I need something like that, but I have to test code. Great idea!

Comment: -1 The whole point is to avoid listing the checkboxes explicitly.

Comment: Yes, but what if you expand the application and at some point you do not want every single checkbox in the program to be checked? You can localize the checkboxes into this vector, and iterate through this vector whenever you want this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In C++Builder, you can place all of your `TCheckBox*` pointers into an array or `std::vector`, which you can then loop through when needed, eg:

```
TCheckBox* cb[10];

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    cb[0] = CheckBox1;
    cb[1] = CheckBox2;
    ...
    cb[9] = CheckBox10;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cb[i]->Checked = true;
}
```

If you have a lot of checkboxes and do not want to fill in the entire array by hand, you can use a loop instead:

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cb[i] = (TCheckBox*) FindComponent("CheckBox" + IntToStr(i+1));
}
```